# Killing a program that I don't know the location of with a batch file

Tags: windows, batch

So I'm trying to make a batch file that will kill a program where the location of it changes every update, it has to be possible to find the program location and kill it within the same batch file, right?

Comment: Does the name change? [Taskkill - end one or more processes. - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/taskkill.html) can use wildcards ...

Comment: killing a program based upon location is not a problem. It will become impossible if the name changes too.

Comment: @LPChip If it's the same basename with an appended version number you can use taskkill.

Comment: The name does not change, only the location does

Comment: @Kevin15673 Then you can use [PsKill - Kill processes by name or process ID - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/pskill.html)

Comment: @DavidPostill Thank you, I think I figured out what I needed to know from that, my batch file seems to work how I want it to now.

Comment: Comments converted to an answer.

Comment: @DavidPostill yeah, I am aware. I was more thinking of spyware kind of name that is a bunch of random letters in a random location.

Comment: @LPChip nah, I was just trying to make a file to automatically update one of my apps by closing it and re-opening it, but I couldn't find anything about closing an application just by the name

Comment: @Kevin15673 you should look into TASKLIST and TASKKILL then. Both use the same syntax, the first is for finding out info about a running process, and the second is to kill it. So if you get TASKLIST to return your program, then use that command with parameters, and replace tasklist for taskkill to kill it. Tasklist and taskkill do require the beginning of the name to be the same though, but wildcards upto the end can be inserted.

Comment: @LPChip David's solution worked for me, but thank you.

Comment: @Kevin15673 you may want to hit the checkmark button on his answer then, to indicate that you no longer need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Is it possible to find the program location and kill it within the same batch file?

Yes. If the name changes you may be able to use  [Taskkill - end one or more processes. - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/taskkill.html) which supports wildcards.

If the name is constant you can use `pskill`:

> **Kill processes by name or process ID.**
>
> Syntax
>
> ```
> pskill [- ] [-t] [\\computer [-u user] [-p passwd]] process_name | process_id
> ```

And specify the `process_name`.

Source [PsKill - Kill processes by name or process ID - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/pskill.html)